# Is this correct "Users failed to assign"?

Tags: grammar

As a user of a platform, you can mass assign users to the team. If there will be some problems with assigning, then you will get an email with the list of users who failed to assign. Is it correct to name email subject "Users failed to assign"? And the text "Some users failed to assign to the team"

Comment: I would prefer "Failed to assign users".  It's the same length, but doesn't imply that it's the users' fault.

Answer (score 2):

"Some users failed to assign to the team" implies (to me, at least) that the users are responsible for the failure.

"Some users could not be assigned to the team" follows a common pattern for reporting errors and conveys the situation you mentioned.

Edit:

As an email subject line, there are 2 common formulations and which you use depends on whether you consider a partial set of users not being assigned an error.

Error case: "Batch process failed: some users could not be assigned to team"

Non-error case: "Batch process completed completed with some issues: some users could not be assigned to team"

You can (and probably should) make edits so the messages have a consistent voice with other communications from the platform.

Comment: How would you name an email subject? In few clear words.

Comment: Are you asking for an email subject line?

Comment: Yes, that was also in my description above. "Is it correct to name email subject "Users failed to assign"?"

Comment: I see.  I'll edit the answer.